# Session not working html

Tags: php, html, session

I am confused. I am trying to make these links appear only when a user has logged in.

But something weird is happening.

Here is my code in index.php...

```
// at the beginning of the page i have
session_start();
....
....
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">


                 <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#about"> <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){echo 'Profile';?></a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#services"><?php if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) echo 'Post Links';?></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio"><?php if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) echo 'My Views';?></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact"><?php if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) echo 'Logout';?></a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

It does not work. I then made a dummy .php to test if my session works.

```
    <?php session_start();?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) echo "Session is up and runnig";?>
</body>
</html>
//I get Session is up and runnig
```

And it works. So I am confused. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where is `$_SESSION['user'] = "John Doe";` being assigned?

Comment: In login.php did not include it here...

Comment: use error reporting then and check your lgos, I can't help you any further

Comment: I do not think the assignment of the session is a problem because it works in the dummy .php file

Comment: yeah, you're right...  ^^^  syntax error `if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){echo 'Profile';` and error reporting would have told you that. Parse error end of file.... etc. Use proper bracing techniques. ***Solved***. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: You are write. The problem I was not getting any errors is because it was=index.html file, I then changed it to index.php.

Comment: *"Here is my code in index.php..."* - <= ??? plus, I had a feeling about the use of `.html`.......... instinct??

Comment: you can mark your question as solved if you want to. I posted my answer for you below. Otherwise, others may be inclined to post answers and thinking the question is still open/unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

You have an unclosed brace in

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){echo 'Profile';?>
                                   ^               ^???
```

and error reporting would have thrown you an parse error (end of file) similar to:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in the line X

Do make it a habit to use proper bracing techniques.

```
if(condition) {...}
```

Not doing so, could have adverse effects later on when using complex coding.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Not to mention my *Spidey sense* tingling about the use of `.html` rather than `.php`

Yet your question stated *"Here is my code in index.php..."* but you said in comments that your file is `.html`. That isn't being parsed as PHP (by default), unless you instruct Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP.

Plus, you may benefit from using a ternary operator instead.

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php